# Html tags not being inserted in database , when using pagedown

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, pagedown

I am using pagedown as my editor, now what i get i my database once i submit is the following:

```
This is what i love about 

`[A-Z]+` - One or more capitalcase ASCII caracters.

`[^A-Z]*` - We are using negated chracter class here by using the ^ sign, basically we are saying, look for any character besides the one in the [] brackets, * means zero or more times.
  | - Or

`[^A-Z]+` - Look for any character besides the one in the [] brakets, another negated character class. + means one or more times.

`g` - We add the global flag, so we get all possible matches and don't just stop at one match.
```

My expected output is each of those line wrapped in a separate paragraph. Also, as i am typing in the pagedowneditor and see the live update below the editor:

[image]

Now if i check the dev tool:

[image]

I can see that here the text is perfectly wrapped in separate paragraphs , but why is't the same inserted in my database ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't really tell what you're asking, or what you're outputting on/with, but here's what I'll say;

Your database is not working on the same format as an HTML page.  And generally that shouldn't bother you.  If you're looking to display that information onto an HTML page, use something like PHP to echo it in, with HTML tags, and separate them that way.